# Spring Boot - Externalize Database Settings

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I have a JAVA project developed with Spring Boot.

The database settings are in the default resources/application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.********:1521/BDHML
spring.datasource.username=********
spring.datasource.password=********
```

The application will run through the command:

```
java -jar **CONFIGURAÇÃO** app-cosolidar.jar
```

I need to put the database settings in a .properties file external to the project.

How can I do this?

What should the .properties file look like?

Should I change any .java files?

What setting should I put in java -jar?

Regards, Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide command line arguments while running jar.

`java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file://<path>/application.properties`

You can also pass a folder location where the application will search for the files.

`java -jar app.jar --spring.config.name=application,jdbc --spring.config.location=file://<path to config folder>`

Refer this link for more understanding. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar

Answer (score 0):

```
You would be able to launch your spring boot application with the external properties file path as follows:

java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config
```